# Why has my Bootstrap Jumbotron lost its left padding?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Minimal example of Jubtotron. The left and right padding has disappeared.

https://jsfiddle.net/3azmutot/1/

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Jumbotron</h1>
<p>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party.</p>
</div>
```

It has padding in the docs.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jumbotron needs to be in a element with the class 'container' to have padding applied.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
        <p>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3azmutot/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the jumbotron to be full width, add the .container within like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
        <p>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```